# Rotation in edit mode

Tags: edit-mode, axis

I want to make animation of a pant folding.... from top view
I have rotated the half side of pant along y axis its good. now I want bottom half of that side to rotate along x to make it half folded in x direction but it doesn't rotate properly. what can i do?

[image]

[image]

Comment: First of all, the pivot point along which you rotate is _Median_. That's why it rotates around the center of the selected vertices. But even if you set a different pivot point, then simply rotating the vertices in _Edit Mode_ will simply change the mesh, you cannot keyframe this for an animation. To animate the mesh, you have to use shape keys - but they will not rotate the vertices, just move them straight from start position to end position. I guess what you want to do or need to do is using an armature with bones or make everything separate pieces and keyframe the animations.

Comment: For something like a folding box in Blender using bones, which you can adapt for your trousers as well, there are tutorials on Youtube. This is a more recent one: [Folding Box Packaging Animation in Blender](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O1em_ijMvUk)

Comment: ok.... Thanks....

Comment: so in other words you have to make a (rather simple) rig to make this folding look good :) looking up a simple rigging tutorial should do.